# Ubuntu does not show correct icon despite it being set up correctly

Tags: unity, icons, .desktop

PyCharm allows to create the icon for you via command. Here's the content of `~/.local/share/applications/jetbrains-pycharm.desktop`:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Version=1.0
Type=Application
Name=PyCharm
Icon=/opt/pycharm-2016.2/bin/pycharm.png
Exec="/opt/pycharm-2016.2/bin/pycharm.sh" %f
Comment=The Drive to Develop
Categories=Development;IDE;
Terminal=false
StartupWMClass=jetbrains-pycharm
```

The icon link is correct, to be sure I even did

```
sudo chown myUser /opt/pycharm-2016.2/bin/pycharm.png
```

on top of making sure it's readable (since everything else there was owned by `root`).

It still won't work. That is, Kupfer shows the currect icon when I enter PyCharm, it starts correctly, but then when hitting Alt-Tab, or at the application icon list on the side, it's just a grey question mark.

There is no other desktop entry for PyCharm on ~/Desktop or /usr/share/applications/.

What am I missing? How can it still go wrong? It used to work perfectly with Pycharm 2016.1

Comment: What happens if you remove the `StartupWMClass=jetbrains-pycharm` line?

Comment: @ByteCommander nothing changes.

Comment: Maybe you might have to log out and back in (or even reboot?) for the change to take effect. And you are 100% sure that there are no other .desktop files for PyCharm in `/usr/share/applications` or `~/.local/share/applications`?

Comment: @ByteCommander Restarting did not help, and yes I am positive.

Comment: Sorry, then I can't help. I use PyCharm from the getdeb.net repository, that one has no such issues.